# Не удается применить индексирование через [] к выражения типа int

Tags: c#

Не знаю почему не удается обратиться к элементу внешнего массива

```
class Programm
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      int a = 5, z = 10;
      int[] i = {3,5,2,9,0,11,6,4,8,1};
      static int method(int i, int a)
      {
         int[] p = new int[a]
         for (int l = 0; l<= a; l++)
         {
            p[l] = i[l]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Потому что i это не внешний массив, а параметр функции

Comment: Вообще ваш код странен, похоже вы не понимаете что делаете

Comment: Андрей NOP , спасибо за наводку. Код я еще не дописал.

Comment: Старайтесь, пожалуйста, прикладывать код текстом, а не картинками

Comment: @Viktorov: не "старайтесь", а "прикладывайте")

Comment: Параметры функции виднее полей класса. Если хотите одинаковые имена, пишите `this.i` когда работаете с полем. И большая просьба код не картинкой прикреплять а именно форматировать как код.

Answer (score 1):

У вас i в параметрах метода указана как одно число, а не массив. Ну и для того, чтобы этот метод существовал не просто так, вам надо его вызывать. Должно быть так

```
class Programm
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      int a = 5, z = 10;
      int[] i = {3,5,2,9,0,11,6,4,8,1};
      static int method(int[] i, int a)
      {
         int[] p = new int[a]
         for (int l = 0; l<= a; l++)
         {
            p[l] = i[l]
         }
      }
      method(i, a);
   }
}
```